# How to convert age to age range and insert to DB

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I had a task that I have to complete within one hour. I have a form that adds records to the database which looks like this

```
$member_age = $_POST['member_age'];
$ins = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO test SET member_age='$member_age'");
```

I have a new task which requires me to take the members age and convert it into an age range and then, finally, insert that age range into a new table called `age_range`.

The age ranges are as followed:

- 7-9 years
- 10-13 years
- 14-17 years
- 18+

An expected input could be, 12. The expected output following this behaviour should be 10-13. How can I achieve this?

Comment: time is ticking, better spend that on trying something yourself than asking others

Comment: I do not want to use other people, it would just be nice if someone would help me with this task. I do not need a ready solution, only help :)

Comment: "add the table" do you mean add a new column called `age_range` or update the column `age_range` like you have done with `member_age` ? PS, your SQL is prone to injections, why do schools still teach people depreciated, out of date, security risk methods still?

Comment: @Jaquarh I have a variable "member-age" in my form. Based on this variable, I would like to enter the record in the "age-range" table (which already exists):
7-9
10-13
14-17
18+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, `@` is clearly showing that `mysql_*` is depreciated, and in-fact, completely removed after PHP 5.6 (for a reason). So, I'm answering this using PDO for your learning benefit.

Secondly, your question is extremely unclear so I'm going to answer it as I perceived it. [You can see this working over at w34l](https://3v4l.org/eeCL1).

*Update: There was a few issues with the `PDOStatement::execute()` where I forgot to pass the binding values as an array and added to give some more information and 'moving on' pointers.*

```
# Lets first check it is set and is numeric
if ( !isset ( $_POST['member_age'] ) && !is_numeric ( $_POST['member_age'] ) )
    die ( 'Missing argument or argument is not numeric.' );

# Establish connection to DB
try {
    $pdo = new \PDO ( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;', 'username', 'password' , [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
    ] );
} catch ( \PDOException $e ) die ( $e->getMessage () ); # Debug

# Insert new record into test
$stmt = $pdo->prepare ( 'INSERT INTO test (member_age) VALUES (?);' );
$stmt->execute ( array ( $_POST['member_age'] ) );

unset($stmt); # Clean up

# Create a configuration for ages
$ageRange = [
    '0-6'   => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
    '7-9'   => [7,8,9],
    '10-13' => [10,11,12,13],
    '14-17' => [14,15,16,16]
    # 18+ will be if this returns empty
];

# Loop through age configuration to find age range
foreach ( $ageRange as $range => $ages) {
    if ( in_array ( $_POST['member_age'], $ages ) ) {
       # Insert the age range
       $stmt = $pdo->prepare ( 'INSERT INTO age_range (age_range) VALUES (?)' );
       $stmt->execute ( [$range] );
       exit();
    }
}

# If it got here, they must be 18 or over
$stmt = $pdo->prepare ( 'INSERT INTO age_range (age_range) VALUES (?)' );
$stmt->execute ( ['18+'] );
```

I am assuming you have a table which you want to store the users age range based on a given value. Therefor, if the given age value is 12, you want to insert 10-13 into this table. Hope this answers your question.

Note, you can use `$pdo->lastInsertId ()` to get the value of a **primary key** column from your `test` table. You could then attach this to your `age_range` table so you can cross reference the information with the `test` table to ensure integrity of solution. [See it working over at DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wE3BHEFwob7pcszS6GzyEy/1)

```
foreach ( $ageRange as $range => $ages) {
    if ( in_array ( $_POST['member_age'], $ages ) ) {
       # Insert the age range
       $stmt = $pdo->prepare ( 'INSERT INTO age_range (age_range, testId) VALUES (?, ?)' );
       $stmt->execute ( array ( $range, $pdo->lastInsertId () ) );
       exit();
    }
}
```

Then to test integrity you could use something like this

```
SELECT test.member_age, age_range.age_range
FROM age_range
INNER JOIN test
ON age_range.testId = test.id;
```